# Visual Studio (TFS), Open the workspace version of a file in changeset

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

While viewing the changesets or history, trying to open the displayed file in list results in opening the server version, the only way I have found to open the my workspace version is to right click, select "open in the source control explorer" and then from the list find the file and open it.

Is there a short cut to opening the file in the workspace? I am using VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such option by default. Changesets contain the history of each item in version control. You can view a changeset to get information about:

- which files were changed
- what the exact changes were
- who changed the files
- what the check-in comment contains
- which work items are associated with the changeset
- which policy warnings appeared

If you want to open the file in solution explorer, you need to get the changeset version into your workspace and open the file.

Comment: i only want my workspace version of the file to open, maybe I need an extension.